# How to design panel like this in sencha touch 2

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I worked in sencha touch for almost a month, but i can't find a way to design UI like below in sencha.

[image]

Above panel is created using Jquery mobile.

How to create panel like this in sencha ?

Sencha touch panel not looks as beautiful like above

Comment: Just looks like some buttons in a panel to me... is that in a popup, or the whole screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's just some buttons in a panel. They would roughly be below. You'd have to edit the CSS (border radius, shadows, and whatnot), but the basic setup is pretty simple:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout:{
        type:'hbox'
    },
    items:[
        {
            xtype:          "button",
            text:           'Register with X',
        },
        {
            xtype:          "button",
            text:           'Use Facebook Account',
        },
        {
            xtype:          "button",
            text:           'Use Twitter Account',
        }
    ]
};
```